# Retrieving and saving values from array of textboxes to an array of integers

Tags: arrays, vb.net

first of all i am a beginner to VB and currently I am working on a school assignment to develop a roulette game. I have 49 betting fields in custom textboxes (for validating purposes) and they are as follows `Dim BetBoxes() As TextBox = {ctxtFirstHalf, ctxtEven....ctxt 36}`. I also have an array (SavedBets) of integers that share the same names except for the prefix. Now when I've added the bets I want, I press bet-button I would like to save the values of filled textboxes to respective integers in the integer array.

How do I check and save the values of the textboxes as integers on the other array? Other ways to implement this neatly are also welcome.

Comment: have you try my answer ? .. any comment ? .. or have you figured it out by yourself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it up similar to the way online casinos are setup.

Use labels with pictures of the numbers and fields you want them to represent(Paint can do this easily).  Instead of using stacks of chips, use the Text property to display the bet amount.  You won't need any extra arrays.

When the ball has chosen a number you simply read the appropriate labels' text property to see if you have a winner then calculate the winning from that value.  The Controls collection is indexed by number or name as string.

Once the winnings are calculated a simple loop will clear all the text properties of the labels.

You can have the player chose the bet amount, then click on the field to add the bet.  A common Click event handler will allow you to add the bet to the clicked label.  Numericupdown controls would work to choose the bet amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Structure and ListOf ..

```
Structure DataBets
  Dim TextBox as TextBox
  Dim Value as Integer
End Structure

Dim lBet as List(Of DataBets)
Dim stBet as DataBets = New DataBets
```

When your ctxFirstHalf filled ..

```
stBet.TextBox = ctxFirstHalf
stBet.Value = val(ctxFirstHalf.Text)
lBet.Add(stBet)
```

To access it ..

```
Msgbox lBet(0).Value '---->this will show your ctxFirstHalf int
```